# Does python mako template support connitue/break in loop context?

Tags: python, templates, loops, mako

Is it possible to use continue/break in a %control structure loop.

For example:

```
% for x in range(1):
 % continue
% endfor
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried it out yourself?

Comment: sory~ That's why i ask here. the code i post above it not working, continue should go to <% continue%>. I don't know much about mako and it's save time to ask question here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. You use `<% continue %>` and `<% break %>`.

Example:

```
from mako.template import Template 
t = Template( 
""" 
% for i in xrange(5): 
    % if i == 3: 
        <% break %> 
    % endif 
    ${i} 
% endfor 
% for i in xrange(5): 
    % if i == 3: 
        <% continue %> 
    % endif 
    ${i} 
% endfor 
""") 
print t.render()
```

Output:

```
0 
1 
2 
0 
1 
2 
4
```

Comment: For those that are still too lazy to read this: Yes, it does support it.

Comment: if I'm reproducing this correctly, the continue statement cannot be embedded in an include subtemplate but must occur in  the template where the for loop is defined unfortunately.